# How to DRY up prototype javascript method definitions?

Tags: javascript

I'm coming back to "raw" Javascript, and I'm writing classes like this:

```
var Person;

Person = (function() {

    function Person() {}

    Person.prototype.run = function() {};

    Person.prototype.jump = function() {};

    Person.prototype.talk = function() {};

    return Person;

})();
```

I feel like the repetition of `Person.prototype` isn't very DRY: it's also harder to avoid line wrapping. Are there common ways of addressing this? For example, one could assign `Person.prototype` to a small variable like `cls`, which would make the lines look more like

```
cls.run = function() {};
```

...but that might be too unconventional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do not have anything in the prototype you can simply assign a new object to it:

```
Person.prototype = {
    run: function() {},
    jump: function() {},
    walk: function() {}
};
```

Otherwise you could use a function such as jQuery's `$.extend()` to merge two objects:

```
$.extend(Person.prototype, {
    run: function() {},
    jump: function() {},
    walk: function() {}
});
```

Comment: ah i completely forgot about that...+1.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what DRY really means.  Dang it, I have to write 'if' and 'function' a lot too.  And I really cant stand 'return' and 'for'.  ;)

DRY is for when functionality is copied and pasted, resulting in bloated code and a high maintenance cost.  In this case, you are complaining more about the language syntax.

BTW, you are probably ahead of (i.e. more DRY) many people by defining methods on objects.

Having said all that, coffeescript allows you to be less verbose.  Way less verbose.  Many times you don't need parenthesis or braces, and you don't need prototype at all.

Comment: Well, repeating `Person` is kind of ugly - you'd have to change quite a few places in a large object if you ever decided to rename it.